# How to underline text and change mouse cursor to pointer in Ace editor

Tags: javascript, css, ace-editor

I want to underline a portion of code in the ace editor when I go with the mouse over it, and even more, to display the mouse cursor as pointer.
I have tried to do it like this:

```
editSession.addMarker(new Range(loc.start.line - 1, loc.start.column, loc.end.line - 1, loc.end.column), "ace_underline", "text")
```

This will not work. What puzzles me though is that if I replace `ace_underline` (the second parameter of `addMarker` function) with `ace_highlight-marker` or `ace_selection` it works in the sense that the range that I want gets colored.

I also tried to create my own css class that looks like:

```
.myCustomMouseOverHighlight {
   text-decoration: underline;
   cursor: pointer !important;
}
```

and then replace the second parameter with `myCustomMouseOverHighlight`, but again, to no avail.

Any pointers will be highly appreciated.

Radu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't work because addMarker adds a div behind the text. try

```
.myCustomMouseOverHighlight {
   border-bottom: 1px solid red;
   position: absolute;
   cursor: pointer !important;
   pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajaxorg.github.io/ace-builds/src/ace.js"></script>
<style>
.myCustomMouseOverHighlight {
   border-bottom: 1px solid red;
   position: absolute;
   cursor: pointer !important;
   pointer-events: auto;
}
</style>
<script>
var Range = ace.Range;
var editor = ace.edit(null, {value: "Hello World"});
editor.container.style.height = "100px";
document.body.appendChild(editor.container);

editor.session.addMarker(new Range(0, 1, 0, 5), "myCustomMouseOverHighlight", "text")

</script>
```

Comment: Excellent solution for making some text appear as a link! Note that pointer-events CSS property is supported in IE only from version 11 and on.